# Chrome Extension - do something on the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I discovered Chrome extensions - my question now is, how can I let click a Button when the Extension will run. For example there is a button with the id='Submit'. How can I simulate a click on this button with chrome Extension.

On the Webpage for example is a button with the id "Button1" - How can I do a Click automatically with the Extension.

Example:

```
 <input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit'>
```

My extension now shoud click this button when i click on the extension

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: I don't really understand your question , Where the button is found ?can you share more details please ..

Comment: @OriEng Is it better now? :)

Comment: A little , but still where the button is ? in your html when you click on extension iocn ? or where ? maybe share little bit more code from your extension that we could help you

Comment: @OriEng There's a button on a Webpage (Google, Youtube, Facebook, etc.) is a button (for example: login button) My Extension should cick this button automatically. And I haven't to click anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So , I hope I understand you right . In your *manifest.json* file under content_scripts->matches you need to set the address of the web where your button you want to click on him , for example if you want in gmail page with all his routes:

```
  "content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["http://mail.google.com/*", "https://mail.google.com/*"],
   "js": ["content.js"],
   "run_at": "document_end"
  }
 ]
```

( /*  Means that in any route in gmail this script will be available)

Then in your *content.js* page you need to get/create your button and just simulate click on him:

```
   document.getElementById("buttonSample").click();
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I searched - Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help! If you please could mark it's as a answer I will thanks you!